# .net core API non regression test best practices

Tags: .net-core

I'm currently working on many .NET Core API projects and encountered a future possible regression.
How do you guys prevent this situation ?

Here's my architecture :

1. API project
2. BusinessLayer
3. API.UnitTests (references 2))
4. API.IntegrationTests (references 1 #for the casts))

An integration test example :

```
[Fact]
    public async Task TestGetAll()
    {
        // Arrange
        var query = "api/v1/xxx/getall";

        // Act
        var response = await _AuthorizedClient.GetAsync(query);

        // Assert
        Assert.True(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);

        var results = JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject<List<MyResult>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        Assert.True(results.Any());
        //Assert.AnythingOn(results);
    }
```

Considering the next version and/or my [colleague] maintenance; with my deserializing cast, an update of the `MyResult` object might be hidden and create a production regression.

I've tried to do my integration test with the dynamic keyword and without casting but it take my much effort.

How do you deal with this situation ?
Are there any best practices ?

[Edit] After some search, I've found this article [Differential Regression Testing for REST APIs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/differential-regression-testing-for-rest-apis/) which looks quite interesting

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, dynamic is not a good practice because it will never fail on build but will fail on execution.
I think you should use something like this :

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string value)
{
    T result = default(T);
    try {
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's was not really the point : my point is how to avoid regression using C# and testing ?